# How can i play an adaptive-video in flutter web using flutter-video-player

Tags: flutter

I've been working on adapting my app, which was originally developed for iOS and Android, to a web version using Flutter. During this process, I encountered a roadblock related to playing media from an m3u8 URL. Despite knowing that this format is supported on the web, I'm facing unexpected playback errors that I didn't encounter on mobile platforms. I'm interested to know if there are developers out there who have managed to successfully implement m3u8 video playback within the context of a Flutter web application. If such individuals exist, I'm seeking guidance on how they accomplished this.

In my attempts to resolve this issue, I experimented with attempting to play the m3u8 content directly from my localhost. This led me to wonder whether there's a necessity to configure specific headers in the headersOption of the VideoPlayerController to enable proper playback. If these headers are indeed required, my challenge lies in deciphering the correct formatting for these headers. As this matter is relatively unfamiliar territory for me, any in-depth insights or step-by-step advice provided by experienced developers would be immensely valuable in helping me overcome this hurdle.

I tried using the m3u8 url from vimeo but got PlatformException